# Create room mailbox in Exchange 2007 - cannot view calendar

Tags: permissions, exchange, exchange-2007

I'm an application developer and I'm trying to play around with Exchange in order to integrate a room booking system with it.

I've created a room mailbox and have set it so that it auto-accepts appointment requests.

When creating an appointment as a standard user I can add the room as a resource and its availability will display.

However, I can add it as a shared calendar to Outlook 2003 (Unable to display the folder. The Calendar folder could not be found) nor can I return the calendar folder using Exchange Web Services (again, could not find the folder).

I've also created an appointment via Exchange Web Services with a room as a resource. The resource was successfully booked (as confirmed when opening it as the room's delegate) but it does not appear on the meeting as viewed by any of the attendees.

Is there anything further I need to do in order to share this calendar?

How do most organizations set up their Exchange with regards to rooms?

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done this is to grant a room administrator (either me or whoever looks after the room) 'Full Access' privileges on the mailbox (something achieved from the ESM) and then to have them add the mailbox to their Outlook client and use the Outlook's sharing permissions to allow read access to the rest of the staff; typically by setting the default to `reviewer`